# Trying to create animation using array function to continuously print out a grid of ints and move each element across 1 place

Tags: c++, arrays, animation

I'm trying to create the effect of 1 traversing down a line of 0's.

My code is simple loop of "last element placed in holder -> all elements = location - 1
-> cout".

When I run it, I don't get my int assigned to 1 showing up on the grid.

Can someone tell me where I've mis-coded?

```
int main()
{
    int arr[10] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}; // Array values declared
    int* arrPtr[10] = {&arr[0], &arr[1], &arr[2], &arr[3], &arr[4], &arr[5], &arr[6], &arr[7], &arr[8], &arr[9]}; // Point array assigned to array elements

    int holder = 1; // Holds last number in sequence
    int* holderPtr = &holder; // Holder pointer

    while (1) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                cout << *arrPtr[i] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }                               // Prints out array 10x to create grid

        holderPtr = arrPtr[9];          // Value of last element in array stored in holder pointer
        for (int m = 9; m >= 1; m--) {
            arrPtr[m] = &arr[m - 1];    // Assigns each pointers value to be equal to previous pointer in array
        }
        arrPtr[0] = holderPtr;          // First element in pointer array assigned value stored in holder pointer

        system("CLS");                  // Resets grid
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please [explain to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) why the line `arrPtr[m] = &arr[m - 1];` matches its comment `Assigns each pointers value to be equal to previous pointer in array`. Explain to your duck how the address `&arr[m - 1]` will be change over time. (Speaking out loud can be effective, as it forces you to use more words then when you mull things over in your head.)

Comment: @JaMiT - The value in the pointer wont change because the element value hasn't changed. I either need to shift the array elements themselves, or have each pointer read each element incrementally.
Replaced arrPtr[m] = &arr[m - 1] w/ -arr[m] = arr[m - 1]. Thank you!

Comment: *"The value in the pointer wont change"* -- I didn't ask you to explain why the value in a *pointer* will not change, but why the value `&arr[m - 1]` will not change. Your comment says that each pointer is assigned the previous pointer in the array, but your statement says that each pointer is assigned the (fixed) address of an element in the *other* array. How is that consistent? *Then again, your code is already way more complicated than is warranted, so I guess as long as you can make it work, it's your creation...*